javascript if(false) acting as though it was true;
I have a javascript variable var clickSnd = false;. What is supposed to happen, is there is a html switch, that calls a function that flips that variable between true and false.
I need this, because I have a function that when called, checks if that variable is true and if so plays a sound.
The problem is that once I set the variable to true once - the sound plays no matter if the variable is true or false.
I debugged the code, and the variable is in fact false.
My function right now looks as follows:


var clickSnd = false;
var snd = new Audio("click-button-140881.mp3");  // Audio

function playAudio() { 
  if (clickSnd) { console.log(clickSnd);  snd.play(); }
}
function toggleclick(tF) {
  clickSnd = tF
  playAudio();
}
function addToDo() {
  /*stuff*/
  playAudio();
}
<form>
  <label for="Sound">Sound:</label>
  <select name="theme" id="Sound" onchange="toggleclick(this.value);" style="font-size: x-large;">
      <option value=false>Off</option>
      <option value=true>On</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="addToDo()" style="font-size: x-large;">Add</button>



The audio doesn't work in the sample, but you can see the issue with the console print statements. It should never be able to log "false". But once clickSnd has been set to true at any point, it will then start printing false.
I am very confused. Please Help.

Hint: console.log(!"false"); vs. console.log(!false);

Values from attributes are strings, not booleans.

clickSnd = tF; vs clickSnd = (tF === 'true');
